# Computing aggregate (e.g running total) with liquid

Tags: liquid, dotliquid

Given an array of `{ name: string; amount: float }`, how does one write out the data running total.

```
{% for entry in my_array %}
   {{ entry.name }}, {{ entry.amount }}, {{ ???running total??? }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
{% assign running_total = 0 %}
{% for entry in my_array %}
  {% assign running_total = running_total | plus: entry.amount %}
{% endfor %}
```